# How will rails 4 affect my current application?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2, rubygems, ruby-on-rails-4

I am new to rails and I would like to upgrade to Rails 4.
At the same time I have been working on a small Beta with Rails 3.2 this past year....

If I upgrade will my current app be affected or will it mess it up. I would really want to upgrade but I don't want my current BETA to encounter any problems.

How will upgrading to rails 4 affect my current application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Breaking news:**
Just released a new free rails cast about Upgrading to Rails4. 
http://railscasts.com/episodes/415-upgrading-to-rails-4

A tip. You can use this gem to check how compatible your environment with rails4. https://github.com/alindeman/rails4_upgrade

Answer (score 3):

Read the upgrade guide here: http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/upgrading_ruby_on_rails.html

You should assume there will be problems that come up. Make sure you're using git or some other SCM tool so you can have a separate branch that you test rails 4 in. You may also want to use RVM so you can separate your rails 4 gemset from your current one.

Comment: Just want to add that this guide is not complete. If you don't have strong test coverage, you are going to run into problems that are going to be difficult to troubleshoot.